# Lucene.net highlight searched term in the text

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.net to search a given document. Requirement is once search is done, it should highlight the searched term in the document. I have seen examples which returns the best fragments. But what i need is to highlight in the main content.

```
     using (StandardAnalyzer standardAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, stopWords))
        {
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Content", standardAnalyzer);
            parser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
            Query qry = parser.Parse(searchText);
            Directory indexDir = CreateRAMDirectory(htmlContent);

            IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(indexDir, true);
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
            searcher.SetDefaultFieldSortScoring(true, true);

            IFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<span style=\"font-weight:bold; background-color:yellow;\">", "</span>");
            SimpleFragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleFragmenter(1000);
            QueryScorer scorer = null;
            scorer = new QueryScorer(qry);

            ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.Search(qry, null, 10000, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;

            Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, scorer);
            highlighter.TextFragmenter = fragmenter;



            foreach (var result in hits)
            {
                int docId = result.Doc;
                float score = result.Score;
                Document doc = searcher.Doc(docId);
                Lucene.Net.Analysis.TokenStream stream = standardAnalyzer.TokenStream("Content", new IO.StringReader(searchText));
        String highlighterData = highlighter.GetBestFragments(stream, searchText, 1000, "");

            }

        }
```

I am a newbie to Lucene.net, how can i get the entire document with searched term content highlighted rather than fragments?

Answer (score 0):

The fragmenter governs how large the chunks of text returned are.  To use the entire field contents, just use [`NullFragmenter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/NullFragmenter.html), instead of `SimpleFragmenter`.

```
Fragmenter fragmenter = new NullFragmenter();
.....
highlighter.TextFragmenter = fragmenter;
```

Comment: i tried this. 
NullFragmenter fragmenter = new NullFragmenter();
fragmenter.Start(entireHtmlContent, standardAnalyzer.TokenStream("Content", new IO.StringReader(searchText)));
String text = highlighter.GetBestFragment(analyzer, "Content", searchText);
Still not getting the complete original document. Could you please include a code sample. Sorry to bug you.

Comment: thanks for the edit, i have the done the exact same thing. Sorry I am still not clear on how to get the entire document with searched text highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, even with the NullFragmenter, it only returned roughly 51 kB of text.
By analyzing the objects, I found out that there is another property at the highligher which sets how large a fragment would be at maximum. Set this value to the length of your string, then the whole document will be processed.

```
highlighter.TextFragmenter = new NullFragmenter();
highlighter.MaxDocCharsToAnalyze = text.Length;
```